# Facebook Graph API - Getting All Friends Likes

Tags: python, facebook, python-2.7, facebook-graph-api, pydev

I am working on FaceBook data mining where I'm trying to query all my friends likes, store them as a dictionary, keyed on each friends name. Iterate over the friends and build up the 'likes'.

*Currently only a single friends "likes" are being returned by the Graph API, and the rest return with null data.(Sample output below)*

**Here is my code:**

```
facebookFriends = graphAPI.get_connections('me', 'friends')['data']

facebookLikes = { myFriends['name'] : graphAPI.get_connections(myFriends['id'], 'likes') ['data']
                 for myFriends in facebookFriends }
print facebookLikes
```

**Sample Output:**

{u'FRIEND1': [{u'category': u'Camera/photo', u'created_time': u'2014-11-12T19:03:39+0000', u'name': u'Nike', u'id': u'470931899629792'}], u'FRIEND2': [], u'FRIEND3': []

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Try putting it in a for loop to retrieve all likes?

Comment: Where do you mean? I have "for myFriends in facebookFriends" which is iterating through

Comment: You will not be able to get likes of friends

Comment: You said you're only getting 1 response, so stick the whole thing in a for loop to get more responses. @Giuls

Comment: Hi Jonathan, I tried that, but no luck:
"for facebookFriends in range(1,10):"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Friend permissions are gone, you can´t get the likes of friends anymore. Check out the changelog for more information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

That means, it will still work in v1.0 Apps, but it will stop working for those after April 2015. You can´t even get all friends after that, since v2.0 you can only get friends who authorized your App too with `/me/friends`.

Comment: I'm running the v2.2 App, and able to retrieve a single friends likes. The friend who's likes I have returned has not explicitly granted access to my app. I assume that her likes are "publicly shared". The issue I'm trying to solve: is why the code is only returning 5 friends and not returning the rest of my 800+ friends?

Comment: may be a bug. you should not get ANY friend likes. your last question is answered in the last paragraph of my answer.

Comment: Hi Luschn, Thanks for the reply. Do you know if there is a way to force my app to be v1.0? I only need to be able to mine this data once, it doesn't need to be a recurring.

Comment: no, you can only use v1.0 with an app create before end of april 2014, you cannot force it for newer apps.